# How to assign function to Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I would like to write a website with some calculators. Each calculator as separate app. I have ealier prepared and tested python code for main functions and now I have problem how to use it in Django. 
I am not using Models, I am not sure but I think as it will be fast calculation by user and no need to store data in database so I decided to use only forms.

- My main question is how to assign function to a Django form?
- By the way,how to put clear python code properly to Django to
  keep 'good    practice of clean code'?

My code:
app *mathcalc:*

```
mathcalc/views.py:

def math_page(request):
    math_form = CalculationForm(request.POST or None)
    content = {
        "form": math_form
    }
    return render(request, 'math.html', content)

class Calculator(object):

    def simpleFunction(self, a, b):
        score = a + b
        print(score)
        print('Tests gone well')

    def otherFunction(self):
        # function here
        return some stuff
```

and

```
in main project/forms.py:

class CalculationForm(forms.Form):
    Years = forms.CharField()                  # a from simpleFunction
    Ammount = forms.CharField()                # b from simpleFunction
```

and

```
in math.html:
<form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I do not know how to connect it all, that after user input some data it will call `def simpleFunction`. How to assign Year charField to variable a and Ammount charField to variable b

Comment: I really don't understand what the Calculator class is for or how it relates to the rest of the code.

Comment: It is an example, Calculator class is my pure python code that I would like to put into Django. Now I think that perhaps it will be better to write other file like calc.py, put there mu full functions and then import this file in views.py

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the whole formhandling code - see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view)